# Validating lists in C#

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations

We're using `DataAnnotations` to validate our model.

A very simplified version of our model is:

```
public class Model
{
    public List<Thing> Things;
}

public class Thing
{
    [Required]
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Now, the funny thing is that if I create a `Thing` with no name and add it to the model, I would expect validation to fail, but it passes (shock horror!).

```
var model = new Model ();
var invalidThing = new Thing (); // No name would fail validation
model.Things.Add(invalidThing );

var validationContext = new ValidationContext(model);
var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, validationContext, validationResults, true);

Assert.False (isValid);  // This fails!
```

I *think* the reason for this is that when you validate the model, it validates each property but not items in the property if it's a collection. `Things` is a property that has no validation, so it passes (despite the fact that it contains invalid item).

How can we ensure that validation also validates items in collection properties? Is there some out-of-the-box validator I could use?

Comment: In context of ASP.NET MVC you don't need to be worried about it. Default model binder takes care of all validation attributes when model binding, even when model binding to a list.

Comment: @RezaAghaei however, when unit testing it, it's not the case. I need a way to unit test the behaviour too. What kind of magic does MVC use to do this?

Comment: It's what the default model binder does. When creating each element, when assigning values to properties, it validates property and add the validation errors to model state. At last, all properties and objects are validated and model state contains all validation errors.

Comment: You can implement some mechanism to perform recursive validation, like what you implemented in the answer or like what you can find [here](http://www.technofattie.com/2011/10/05/recursive-validation-using-dataannotations.html), but in general the default behavior in your question is not surprising IMO. Let's say you had a property of type `Dictionary<string, Thing>` in the `Model` or `Something<Thing>`, then could you expect the `Validator` perform a validation against that property?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have fixed this by creating a custom validator for collections that checks validation on each item. A simplified code would look like this:

```
public class ValidateEachItemAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected readonly List<ValidationResult> validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var list = value as IEnumerable;
        if (list == null) return true;

        var isValid = true;

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            var validationContext = new ValidationContext(item);
            var isItemValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(item, validationContext, validationResults, true);
            isValid &= isItemValid;
        }
        return isValid;
    }

    // I have ommitted error message formatting
}
```

Now decorating the model this way would work as expected:

```
public class Model
{
    [ValidateEachItem]
    public List<Thing> Things;
}
```

Comment: If you have more than single object, validated with this cod, your `validationResults` will collect errors from _all_ validated objects (ValidateEachItemAttribute  created only once). I think this list should be created right before `foreach`.

Comment: Not a valid answer anymore, because as mentioned in the documentation: the bool IsValid(object) method shouldn't be overridden in the derived classes. Instead,  IsValid(object, ValidationContext) should be implemented.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative, if this is `ASP.NET MVC`, would be to implement `IValidatableObject` in your model. Like:

```
public class Model: IValidatableObject
{
    public List<Thing> Things;

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
       //your validation logic here
    }
}
```

Then the result of `ModelState.IsValid` in your `controller` will depend on that implementation of `Validate` method. This is useful when multiple properties of your model are dependent on each other.

Comment: And how exactly are you running the validation logic of the "Thing" class in this model? Your answer doesn't solve the problem i'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior in your question is not surprising, let's describe it. 
Let's say you have a property of type `Dictionary<string, Thing>` or a property of type `Something<Thing>` or an untyped collection containing `Thing` objects in the `Model`, then how could we expect the `Validator` perform a validation against `Thing` objects which are stored in those properties?

We cannot expect `Validator` to perform a validation against `Thing` objects which are stored in those properties, because it doesn't have any information about how it should validate those properties. To validate a property, `Validator` looks for `ValidationAttribute` for that property and since it doesn't find any validation attribute, it doesn't validate that property.

As a result, you need to create some `ValidationAttribute` to do that for you and decorate properties with validation attributes. You can implement something like what you implemented in your answer.

**Note:** In context of ASP.NET MVC you don't need to be worried about it. Default model binder takes care of all validation attributes when model binding, even when model binding to a list.

It's what the default model binder does. When creating each element, when assigning values to properties, it validates property and add the validation errors to model state. At last, all properties and objects are validated and model state contains all validation errors.