# How to validate an item when it is added to the list in C#

Tags: c#, list

I need to validate an item added to a list in C#. I've looked at this article: [Validating lists in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51523346/validating-lists-in-c-sharp), but it isn't working.

```
returnModel.FileSystemItems.Add(new FileManagerFileSystemItem
{
    Name = item.FolderName,
    Key = item.FolderId.ToString(),
    Key2 = "folder",
    Key3 = key3,
    IsDirectory = true,
    HasSubDirectories = list.Any(a => a.ParentId == item.FolderId),
    DateModified = DateTime.Now,
    Size = 0,
    Metadata = metadata,
    Permissions = key3 == FileManagerFolderType.Private.ToString() ? GetPrivateFolderPermissions() : GetPublicFolderPermissions(hasFileManager)
});
```

So I want to make sure they set `Key` to an id or make sure `Key2` is set to "Files" or "Folders"

I'm not trying to validate really the end-user, but validate to make sure the developer has set all the necessary properties when using the list.

Of course, I could add a `Validate()` method within the class to validate it after they are done adding to it, but then the developer would have to know to add that code at the end, which kind of defeats the purpose.

I tried to do the example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51523347/13698253, but it will never hit the breakpoint in the code.

Any ideas on how to solve this OR do I just need to add my own validation method at the end of the list that will make sure that the developer added everything properly.

This is not in a model validation for the model state of the controller. This is just in a normal class that might not be tied to MVC etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you might be overthinking it. Couldn't you just do something like `return ...Add(Validate(new FileManagerFileSystemItem { ...` after adding a `Validate()` method? That would take care of the "when it is added to the list".

Comment: Why not forcing to use a constructor with all the parameters. Like that internally throw and exception if the parameters are invalid. Also replace your `Key2` with an `enum` since it has to be either `NA`, `Folders`, `Files`.

Comment: u still have the option to create own list or enumerable or .. implementation that will validate items acording to your needs.

Comment: @Kit: that will require the developer to add the Validate in each time though? I want to see if there is a way to when they do .Add(), it will validate it auto

Comment: @Franck: let me think of that...

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation of your code?

Comment: I was about to echo Steve's answer... seems like a good solution.

Comment: Go with what @Franck has suggested.  The best way to make sure the data is created properly is to make it so that the developer has almost no way to make a mistake (what the .NET designers called the _Pit of Success_ (https://ricomariani.medium.com/the-pit-of-success-cfefc6cb64c8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own custom List class which will throw an exception if the item being added is invalid:

```
public FileManagerFileSystemItemList : List<FileManagerFileSystemItem>
{
    // edit: added TryAdd as per other's suggestions
    // all this does is wrap the Add call in a try/catch block
    // which would be enough to prevent unwanted exceptions
    // but using Add alone would throw potentially useful exceptions 
    // for the developer to then deal with.
    public bool TryAdd(FileManagerFileSystemItem item)
    {
        try
        {
            Add(item);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    new public void Add(FileManagerFileSystemItem item)
    {
        Validate(item);
        base.Add(item);
    }

    private void Validate(FileManagerFileSystemItem item)
    {
        if (!Guid.TryParse(item.Key, out _))
            throw new Exception("Key is not an id");

        // ... and other validation
    }
}
```

If however you wanted something more generic, you could put the validation into the class to be validated and have it implement an interface that can then be used as a constraint in a ValidatableList:

```
public interface IValidatable
{
    bool IsValid { get; }
    void Validate();
}

public class ValidatableList<T> : List<T> where T : class, IValidatable
{
    public bool TryAdd(T item)
    {
        if (!item.IsValid)
            return false;

        base.Add(item);
        return true;            
    }

    new public void void Add(T item)
    {
        item.Validate();
        base.Add(item);
    }
}

public class FileManagerFileSystemItem : IValidatable
{
    ...
    // rest of your class
    ...

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                Validate();
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Validate()
    {
        if (!Guid.TryParse(Key, out _))
            throw new Exception("Key is not an id");

        // ... and other validation
    }
}

// Now your FileSystemItems property would be an instance of the new List class
...
    ValidatableList<FileManagerFileSystemItem> FileSystemItems ...
...
```

The only potential issue I can see with the above is if the class you want a list of is not one you can modify to add in your validation. In this case you would need a separate validator class that handles this for your object which would look more like:

```
public interface IValidator<T> where T : class
{
    bool IsValid(T item);
    void Validate(T item);
}

public class FileSystemItemValidator : IValidator<FileManagerFileSystemItem>
{
    public bool IsValid(T item)
    {
        try
        {
            Validate(item);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void Validate(T item)
    {
        if (!Guid.TryParse(item.Key, out _))
            throw new Exception("Key is not an id");

        // ... and other validation
    }
}

// and the list class needs to know which class can validate its items
public class ValidatableList<T, TValidator> : List<T> where TValidator : class, IValidator<T>, new()
{
    private readonly TValidator _validator;

    public ValidatableList()
        : base()      
    {
        _validator = new TValidator();
    }

    public bool TryAdd(T item)
    {
        if (!_validator.IsValid(item))
            return false;

        base.Add(item);
        return true;            
    }

    new public void void Add(T item)
    {
        _validator.Validate(item);
        base.Add(item);
    }
}

// Now your FileSystemItems property would be an instance of the new List class
...
    ValidatableList<FileManagerFileSystemItem, FileSystemItemValidator> FileSystemItems ...
...
```

Comment: It's quite overkill to use exceptions for that. The usual approach would be to e.g. name the method `TryAdd` and return a bool.

Comment: maybe whit more generic and abstract implementation like ICollection OP can reuse it with different types

Comment: You could have a more generic class yes @spzvtbg but what the OP is doing is not generic. The validation is specific to the item type.

Comment: @JHBonarius I'm not sure exceptions are overkill in this particular scenario. The idea is to ensure the developer is setting values appropriately.

Comment: The original idea was to force the developer to create the object properly but this does not prevent that. If the dev decide to create a `List<FileManagerFileSystemItem>` he can still create invalid object.

Comment: Maybe, but imho a developer should know that when calling a `Try...` method, they should check if it succeeded. Else you require a developer to implement exception handling. Or it gets caught by some outer existing exception handler, which only logs it or so.

Comment: That's true @Franck, but if the FileSystemItems property on the return model is an instance of this class then that won't be possible. Of course, any models would need to explicitly use this class. But we can't override the base List class.

Comment: Yes indeed @JHBonarius, good exception handling should be a standard part of development.

Comment: i'm just giving it like optipn OP considers. and i confirm @JHBonarius sugestion - it may be better to have a method Add that returns boolean insted of throwing exception

Comment: I have added a TryAdd for completeness as it is likely that developers would sometimes want to avoid exceptions for incomplete instances.

Comment: You all got me thinking so I've added some more generic solutions into my answer.

Comment: @SteveHarris: I have this error: `CS0506 'FileManagerFileSystemItemList.Add(FileManagerFileSystemItem)': cannot override inherited member 'List<FileManagerFileSystemItem>.Add(FileManagerFileSystemItem)' because it is not marked virtual, abstract, or override `

Comment: @SteveHarris: Appears `override` needs to be set to `new` as: `   public new void Add(FileManagerFileSystemItem item)`

Comment: @ttaylor27272727 that is true, whoopsie. Answer updated!

Comment: @SteveHarris: Thanks for the help! I think I'll use both your example and the constructor's answer on the initial question!